# Handle a directory like the www root with .htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess

I have a problem with my deployment of my Laravel application on my sub directory.

Locally my Laravel app is installed on *localhost:8000*; so there is no sub directory.

On my live server, the Laravel app is located on example.tld/myapp.

So whenevery I deploy my app on the live server, I have to change every URL. 
Example

*local: my-img.png to /myapp/my-img.png*

*or xhr requests local: /api/myreq to myapp/api/myreq*

So I am looking for an easier way to make this work with a htaccess 
or is there another way?

So that the url must not be renamed.

Comment: use `RewriteCond` to see if the request you received starts with `/myapp/`.  If not, then use `RewriteRule` to add `/myapp/` in front of what was requested.  Try it out, post your attempt and we can help fix it if required.

Comment: Probably it is better to be defined on the VirtualHost if you have access to it